# How to stop php script execution on php-fpm/nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

Unfortunately calling php `exit()` on php-fpm/nginx configuration does not stop the script immediately while file handles might not be closed.

Some developers suggest calling `fastcgi_finish_request()` but also this does not stop the script.

Others suggest wrapping all code in a catch block:

```
<?php
    class SystemExit extends Exception {}
    try {
       /* PUT ALL THE CODE HERE */
    } catch (SystemExit $e) { /* do nothing */ }
?>
```

and throwing an exception where code stop is needed:

```
if (SOME_EXIT_CONDITION)
   throw new SystemExit(); // instead of exit()
```

This would mean editing all php files to include try/catch block and seems tedious to me.

Are there any other clean solutions?

Comment: `exit` works for me. What exactly happens in your case?

Comment: try the following code: `    echo "You have to wait 10 seconds to see this.<br>";    register_shutdown_function('shutdown');    exit;    function shutdown(){        sleep(10);        echo "Because exit() doesn't terminate php-fpm calls immediately.<br>";    } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found out that it's a `register_shutdown_function` callback that prevents your script from exiting immediately.

PHP shutdown function is designed to be called on any script shutdown when possible. But it has a feature: if one of shutdown callbacks calls exit — script is exiting without calling any other callbacks.

So if you really want to skip a shutdown function in some cases, you should register some killer-function as a very first shutdown callback. Inside that killer-function you will check a kind of singleton for state: do we want to exit? — call `exit()`, otherwise — return.

```
<?php

function killer_function() {
    if ($someGlobalThing->needToExitRightNow()) {
        exit();
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('killer_function');

// ...

function exit_now() {
    $someGlobalThing->exitNow();
    exit();
}
```

(`$someGlobalThing` can be a singleton or some super-global variable or a global registry or whatever you like)

Then calling `exit_now()` will do the trick.