# die() is not stopping code from executing

Tags: php, cgi, exit, fpm, die

the problem is in the following:

```php
echo 'Hello...';

die('I died...');

echo 'HAHAHA!!!';
```

on the web browser it is executing the echo after the die().
on the CLI stops on the die() and does not shows the echo as expected.

My Specs:
PHP 7.4 (FPM)
web server Nginx (also tried with apache with the same result)

Also I had a time long a test server on windows and it was exiting the script when exit or die was called, but somehow on the debian test server is not doing that.

is there something I am missing?
do you guys have any tip?

Thanks in advance....

Update on 2022-07-27 :

script:
[image]

Browser output:
[image]

CLI output
[image]

I've updated the PHP version (same happening):
[image]

@MarkusZeller yes is disabled the opcache:
[image]

still not working...
but somehow on the windows server under php7.4.26 runs the script with the expected die

The development environment is windows with Debian 11 (WSL2) I have also tried it yesterday on a test machine I have in my home with base Debian 11 installed and it has the same issue. Same thing with the Debian 11 test server at work.

@YourCommonSense the script is the same. Here is the nginx path config:
[image]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i think this case strictly related to php fpm (fast cgi), so.. please add [tag:fpm] tag.

Comment: I just tested this on the cli and the browser and in both cases the output I got was "Hello...I died...".

Comment: Did you enable pre-loading or opcache?

Comment: also, have you checked [how to stop php script execution on php-fpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955497/how-to-stop-php-script-execution-on-php-fpm-nginx)?

Comment: @raphael75 : That was what i wanted to have... but somehow in the browser does not goes out

Comment: @BagusTesa i will check the link

Comment: tried same on w3school php editor and output is "Hello...I died..."

Comment: @MarkusZeller 
the opcache is off

Comment: I just do not understand. I never had this problem.... But somehow with 'return' does what I want... Just a bit strange that the die() or exit is not doing it. I was thinking at first it was a problem in my development environment... But after Installing a fresh system it came the same out

Comment: Can't you just upgrade to 8.1? 7.4 is quite old.

Comment: `die` / `exit` is a language construct - it _cannot_ fail. Either you have a typo or PHP is not executed at all.

Comment: @Honk der Hase 
that is what i was thinking from the beginning.... first time happening something like this... i can also do a screen share so you can check (in discord if you want to see)... i replicated the same thing now on my personal machine (before was only on my company laptop and in the new test server environment)

Comment: @Markus Zeller 
I am going to try now with a diferent version ... the problem is that due to some libs i can not apply that to the company project. but the strange is that on the windows server it runs perfectly with 7.4 (somehow).

Comment: Obviously, it is not "die()" but some other issue. You can wrap the die() call in some debugging output, like echo "before die"; and see. there won't be this "before die" either. As you are simply calling a different script in your browser

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the comment but, the problem is even the die being there the script continue to run .... somehow on the terminal it stops there but in the browser not.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have updated the post with the image from the nginx vhost configuration.... Like this you can see that is the same script... and what is happening in this dev environment is also happening in the test server I only saw that after the migration from windows to linux...

Comment: if you look at **your own screenshot** it is not die. **There is no output from die**, nowhere that "I died" can be seen. Which means that die weren't called at all. And not your "keeps running after die".

Comment: You are using a framework. I think that's overloading die().

Comment: @MarkusZeller Actually not we use some php requirements through composer but the base is not a framework. but in this example I am only loading a simple 3 line script nothing more. my only problem to know why the cli makes the expected and the browser output not.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I really do not know what you want to achieve with the comment but open your eyes and see what is in the post. I would not be here posting if I didn't run into this.
the example is there and the 2 runs (CLI and nginx with php-fpm).

Comment: Yes sir! Did what you said! Opened my eyes and looked at your post! I see `Hello...HAHAHA!!!` without any `I died...` in sight!

Comment: Have you tried calling just `die()`? The only *possible* stab into the dark that comes to mind is that php-fpm *somehow* doesn't die when using a non-numeric "exit code". I know it's far-fetched, but…

Comment: @YourCommonSense Which means the `die` statement got skipped somehow/it did not output anything and also didn't die. Which is the perplexing behaviour OP is asking about here. *Assuming* this sample actually works as stated and OP isn't accidentally executing the wrong code…

Comment: @deceze not at all. what the OP is asking is why die, **albeit called**, doesn't stop the execution, whereas the situation is completely different: evidently, die isn't called at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense *IF*, and that's a big *IF*, there's some bug that would cause `die` to not die, and in the process of not dying also to not output the message, that would explain the behaviour OP is observing. That it's happening only in a specific environment further supports this.

Comment: Something like this vaguely points in the same direction: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79948

Comment: Another vaguely related issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79003

Comment: @deceze I am a simple man and follow the ol' Hanlon's guidance: as long as there is no good evidence, assume the human factor, not a malicious bug.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure, but assuming OP isn't a complete moron and the presented evidence is real, that's convincing enough to start looking for PHP bugs.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the links... I was loking also in the bug tracker but only found one with a connection with opcache... at one point didn't pass to my situation because I have it disabled. 
But never less as I wrote earlier this situation did not happen on a windows based server only difference is the PHP version (earlier version to be more precise 7.4.26, in this example I tried with 7.4.30 and 8.1).

Comment: I have found the problem... I removed all PHP extensions and installed only some of them after that the die / exit was not ignored anymore.

I thank you all for the time you gave here... I am going to install every extension individually again and when I get the same error I will edit the post to write which extension was causing that problem...

cya guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Solution:***

The cause of the problem was on the extension **php-uopz**. After installing every extension individually and testing after every install, the behavior only happens after this extension is activated. Hope this helps in case anyone runs into the same issue.